# Image compression for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, image-processing, image-editor

I need an image compression for my Linux machine with the following features:

- Support .png and .jp(e)g files
- Bulk functionality to compress a lot of images at once
- GUI (optional)
- Free
- Linux

At the moment I use [Trimage](http://trimage.org/) image compressor, but I am not satisfied with the results. The loss is no more than 5-10% each time.

Comment: So how much loss are you expecting?

Comment: It always depends of the original size and type. At office, we have an app for Windows which has compressed from 20-70%.

Comment: [Related](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/)

Comment: I found it but `be a command line tool with no gui interface`..I prefer with a GUI

Comment: Then why not use the ImageMagick command-line tools? I have them in some places for bulk-processing. As easy as `mogrify -quality 70 *.jpg`, for example.

Comment: @izzy please add it as an answer. If there will not be any other with a gui, I will choose yours

Comment: And if mine has a GUI, it should fit 100% – see my answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)** should meet your requirements, as your requirements mention a GUI is optional. I'm using that for "batch compression" all the time, which is as easy as

```
mogrify -quality 70 *.jpg
```

(this example compressing all JPEG images in the current working directory to 70%).

- **Support .png and .jp(e)g files:** Yes, and many more formats.
- **Bulk functionality to compress a lot of images at once:** Yes, as pointed out :)
- **Free:** Yes, open-source.
- **Linux:** Yes, and in the repos of all major distributions
- **GUI:** Oh: Yes, infact there is – by the command `display`

[image: ImageMagick GUI]
<sup>`display` offers a GUI to *ImageMagick* (source: [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/ImageMagick#display); click image for larger variant)</sup>